# If I used views for my SSAS DSV, can the relationships in SSAS Data Source View be scripted?

Tags: scripting, view, ssas

I based an SSAS 2005 cube on a data source view comprised of views in the relational layer, nto tables with relationships. I did not use schema binding on the views. Now I need to rebuild two projects from these, but dread having to connect the views' facts and dims all over again in the dsv.
Is there script that will reestablish or remember the relationships, or do i have to create them in the relational layer, or should i just stick to tables when building cubes?
thanks very much
drew

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question, what happened to the original DSV?  The DSV is ultimately just a XML file.  If you check your project folder, it is the Analysis Services Data Source View file with the .dsv file extension.  So if you only want to rebuild the cubes and dimensions, then just add your original DSV to the new project and it should work just like you created one from scratch in the new project.

Using views as a source is generally better than using direct tables since you can use table locking hints like NOLOCK.  Also, you can make modifications to the underlying view without having to alter the DSV.